# TimeoutException in RenderResponse (don't know why)

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm developing a new project, everything seems to be working fine, but when I try to edit some registry, **SOMETIMES** I'm getting the TimeoutException, and God knows how generic is this exception, I don't know why or where is causing this problem, so I desperatly tried to change many things as cache and jsf state saving method to client side, nothing seems to work, so I created a PhaseListener to discover the phase where the exception is happening, it's happening on phase 6 - Render Response, it start well, but before it finish his job (sometimes) the exception is throwed, can anybody give me an ideia about how to solve this problem or why it's happening? I don't know what is the real cause of the timeout exception, some warning just came with the exception:

```
[...]
Informações:   ENDING PHASE: INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
Informações:   STARTING PHASE: RENDER_RESPONSE 6 
Advertência:   JSF1064: Not able to find resource, jquery/jquery.js, by library,primefaces. 
Advertência:   JSF1064: Not able to find resource,  jquery/jquery-plugins.js, by library, primefaces. 
Advertência:   java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Exceptions.makeIOException(Exceptions.java:81)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:958)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:682)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:161)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:449)
at java.nio.channels.Channels$WritableByteChannelImpl.write(Channels.java:458)
at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:343)
at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:132)
at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:153)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:643)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.blockAfterWriteIfNeeded(OutputBuffer.java:951)
... 71 more
..............
Advertência:   JSF1064: Not able to find resource, primefaces.js, by library, primefaces.
Advertência:   java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Exceptions.makeIOException(Exceptions.java:81)
..............
Informações:   ENDING FASE: RENDER_RESPONSE 6
Advertência:   JSF1064: Not able to find resource, jsf.js, by library, javax.faces.
Advertência:   java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.Exceptions.makeIOException(Exceptions.java:81)
[...]
```

I'm using:

- Netbeans 7.4
- JDK 7 (1.7.0_45)
- Glasffish 4 (build 89)
- JSF 2.2.6
- Primefaces 4

Thank you guys!

Comment: Are you a) using/including a jquery bundle outside of what primefaces provides b)have anywhere in your app, where you have an `<h:form/>` within another `<h:form/>`? Also, what do you mean by "edit a registry"?

Comment: a) - No, I'm not
b) - I don't think so, but I'll look it right now
About edit I mean try to edit a persisted registry (like Student or Teacher), but now I figured out that this error also happens when I'm going to create a new registry

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Is there any chance of my GUI is being too "heavy"? I mean, my GUI have a looooooooot of forms (not one within another), tabs, dialogs, and fields and such. Can you give me any advice about GUI with too many components?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're describing a known issue that appears on GlassFish 4 when there are more large static resources loaded at once than there are available HTTP worker threads. It should be fixed in 4.0.1. For now, you can find a patch here:

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20681

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to apply this patch.